# Installing Tensorflow, NumPy and Pandas on the same machine

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, dependencies, dependency-management

If I try and install TensorFlow on my machine, it'll install numpy 1.19.5

If I try and install Pandas, it'll install numpy 1.22

If I stick with numpy 1.19.5 and try to import pandas, I get a complaint from pandas:

```
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

If I go with numpy 1.22, I get

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_2/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array
```

Which I've heard means it's because tensorflow can't run on 1.22

So what am I supposed to do to have pandas and tensorflow working at the same time?

Comment: Did you try downgrading `pandas` to a version `numpy`-compatible with `tensorflow`?

Comment: @bottledmind this was my immediate idea, but I can't find anything about which pandas version is suited to numpy 1.19.5

Comment: what `pandas` and `tensorflow` versions are you using? Didn't get the error with `pandas`==1.3.4 and `numpy`==1.19.5.

Comment: @bottledmind the versions given to me with `pip install pandas` and `pip install tensorflow-macos`. The latter is 2.7.0 and the former 1.3.5 with numpy==1.19.5

Comment: So, we might be messing with macos... Did you try `pandas`==1.3.4? For ubuntu even 1.3.5 has a requirement of `numpy>=1.17.3`. Anyway, you can `pip install` through some latest `pandas` versions and check what `numpy` version they require from console logs

Comment: @bottledmind Yes, and an M1 macos. Are you referring to a manner of just brute force pip installing older pandas versions until it uses a version of numpy I want?

Comment: Exactly. Not a perfect way to solve the problem, but seems to be the only one for now

Comment: That second error most likely has nothing to do with your numpy version, it's just buggy code. Impossible to say more without seeing the code that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pandas version==1.3.5` which supports all later versions of `Tensorflow 2.6 to 2.9` and `Numpy version >= 1.17.3`

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the case from my attempts. Up to Pandas 1.3.3 is supported:
Because pandas (1.3.4) depends on numpy (>=1.20.0)
 and tensorflow (2.6.0) depends on numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0), pandas (1.3.4) is incompatible with tensorflow (2.6.0).
So, because mnist depends on both tensorflow (2.6) and pandas (1.3.4), version solving failed.